# How to display data filtered by ID?

Tags: angular

There are two models.

model 1:

```
export class Project{
    constructor(
        public project_id?:number,
        public name?: string,
        public comments?: string,
        public version?: string,
        public date?: Date
    ) { }
}
```

model 2:

```
export class Test{
    constructor(
        public test_id?:number,
        public projects_id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public date?: Date,
        public is_check?: string
    ) { }
}
```

How can I display data from the "Test" model by filtering them by id `projects_id`. That is, it is necessary to filter the data from the "Test" model in accordance with the data from the "Project". 
Here is the function of loading data without a filter:

```
  tests: Array<Test>;
  projects: Array<Project>;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.getTests();
      }

      getTests() { 
        this.servTest.getTests().subscribe(
          tests => this.tests = tests
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter as follows,

```
this.servTest.getTests().subscribe(
  tests => this.tests = tests.filter(t=>t.projects_id === yourProjectId);
);
```

Comment: I did not understand this part `(t=>t.projects_id = project_id)` How does the function know that I'm taking an identifier from the "Project" model?

Comment: that dpepends on your logic

Comment: and why "=", and not "=="?

Comment: yeah taht was a mistake,it should be ===